# MySQL PHP ID in one table and not another

Tags: php, mysql

```
| Fixture_ID | League_ID | Home_Team | Away_Team 
|          1 |         1 |         1 |         2 
|          2 |         1 |         2 |         3 
|          3 |         1 |         3 |         1
```

```
| Result_ID | Fixture_ID | Home_Goals | Away_Goals 
|         1 |          1 |          2 |          0
```

```
| Team_ID | Team_Name   |
|       1 | Team A  
|       2 | Team B      
|       3 | Team C
```

How do I join the tables to show only the fixtures that haven't had results inputed but output the actual team names (Team A v Team B) when showing the fixture (in a drop down list)?

The following code works for outputting all fixtures:

```
echo '<td> <select name ="fixture_id">';    

// TRY TO SHOW FIXTURES WITH NO RESULTS
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT  f.*, t1.Team_Name AS Home, t2.Team_Name AS Away
                        FROM Fixture        f
                        INNER JOIN Team     t1 ON f.Home_Team = t1.Team_ID
                        INNER JOIN Team     t2 ON f.Away_Team = t2.Team_ID');


$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    echo '<option>' . $row['Home'] . ' v ' .  $row['Away'] . '</option>';
}  

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL should look like this:

```
SELECT  f.*, t1.Team_Name AS Home, t2.Team_Name AS Away
FROM Fixture        f
INNER JOIN Team     t1 ON f.Home_Team = t1.Team_ID
INNER JOIN Team     t2 ON f.Away_Team = t2.Team_ID
LEFT JOIN Result    r ON f.Fixture_ID = r.Fixture_ID
WHERE r.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Your answer is enough, no need to rewrite it again :)

Comment: @Sam Higgs: Please mark my answer as the correct one (even if there is no other answer available) and upvote it, if you are allowed to do this already. Thanks!